# ckeditor slow to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I just installed the very basic level of ckeditor and noticed that it takes quite a while to load on each page load.

Here's a (HTML5) gif of the loading (this is slightly faster than normal): [gif here](http://zippy.gfycat.com/BlankQuarterlyCow.mp4?2)

I'm not doing anything that would pop out as problematic so I'm not sure why it takes so long to load. Is there any way to have the textarea never show up, so that it doesn't look as if it's "popping" into the ckeditor like it does in the gif?

These are the only JS scripts that I have on this page:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Please help

Comment: And your html/initialisation code?

Comment: @Petah The HTML is just a textarea (id `text_field`), the initialization code is `CKEDITOR.replace('text_field', { customConfig : 'config.js' });`. The config.js file's only difference from the default that came with ckeditor is that I made the toolbar location on the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

**Replace those scripts with:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.3.2/ckeditor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.3.2/adapters/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Remove the current `<textarea>` and replace your current `CKEDITOR.replace(...)` script with this:

```
<script>
    $('<textarea/>').attr('id', 'text_field').css('visibility', 'hidden').appendTo('#ckeditorArea').ckeditor(function(textField) {
        $(textField).css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
</script>
```

This uses the **jQuery adapters** method `.ckeditor()` to initialize the editor on the new element, rather than using the traditional CKEDITOR.replace() method.

Initially the textarea will be in the page but hidden, then will be visible once the CKEditor interface is applied.

Comment: Suggesting to replace his local files with versions hosted in a CDN should be done after checking that it does really bring a performance benefit, but as it is now he seems to talk just about the CKEditor initialization time. Besides that, you're now including an extra file that means another request and an increased delay but if you want to use it just to hide the container and initialize a CKEditor instance, you don't need that. Then, you should check correctly if the editor works, because Chrome has issues depending on how you hide the container.

Comment: And lastly, you need to change the visibility of the editor container, not the textarea.

Comment: I agree the extra additions seem to just add to it but unfortunately using the library directly required a definition of its location **on the web server** which...I'm not sure how to do with it being not on the server n all.  I agree with the visibility comment though, good catch.  I actually think ballooning the code a little more for that action would produce a result worth the extra processing (animating opacity in after load).  That was the other reason I went with the jQuery adapter - no callback on the `replace()` - but now I think I have a way around it.  I'll update when it's perfect.

Comment: PS - I'm no expert, but a 500KB JS file that's MINIFIED...probably not speeding anything up there lol CKEditor is nuts.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor Loading performance details:
http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-Loading-performance-details

Comment: That's an article from 09 talking about how a 2.5s load is fine. Nowadays 2.5 seconds  is an eternity!